# Teamcity AssemblyInfo patcher not working

Tags: teamcity, assemblyinfo

I get the following error message in the TeamCity build log when trying to use the AssemblyInfo Patcher:

*[Update assembly versions] Updating assembly version in C:...\work\xxxxxxxxxx\GlobalAssemblyInfo.cs
[10:15:28][Update assembly versions] Assembly file version was specified, but couldn't be patched in file C:...\work\xxxxxxxxxxxxx\GlobalAssemblyInfo.cs. Is necessary attribute missing?
[10:15:28]*

The GlobalAssemblyInfo.cs file is in the same dir as the solution file.
Maybe permissions issue?

Using TeamCity Enterprise 9.1.5 (build 37377)

My GlobalAssemblyInfo.cs:

```
using System;
using System.Reflection;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;


[assembly: AssemblyCompany("xxxxxxx")]
[assembly: AssemblyProduct("xxxxxxx")]
[assembly: AssemblyCopyright("xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx")]
[assembly: AssemblyTrademark("")]


[assembly: AssemblyConfiguration("xxxxx")]
[assembly: AssemblyDescription("xxxxxxx")]


[assembly: CLSCompliant(true)]


[assembly: ComVisible(false)]


[assembly: AssemblyVersion("1.0.0.0")]
[assembly: AssemblyInformationalVersion("1.0.0.0")]
```

Edit:

Even tried with Assembly version format: 0.0.1.1 hardcoded in TeamCity...

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

There should be the following attributes in the GlobalAssemblyInfo.cs file: AssemblyVersion, AssemblyFileVersion and AssemblyInformationalVersion. See the [documentation](https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/TCD9/AssemblyInfo+Patcher) for details.

Answer (score 0):

In my case a **AssemblyInfo.cs** file was missing in the project.
Make sure you have this file with the following attributes:

```
[assembly: AssemblyVersion("1.0.0.0")]
[assembly: AssemblyFileVersion("1.0.0.0")]
```